# ¿Cómo formatear un diccionario c#?

Tags: c#, json

Estoy realizando una consulta a una tabla con c# a través de un `dataAccess`, me devuelve un `dataTable` y los parseo en un `webMethod` a formato JSON y retorno la respuesta en este formato:

```
"datos": [
        {
            "idPermiso": 1,
            "nombre": "Catálogos",
            "idUsuario": 11478,
            "email": "labm"
        },
        {
            "idPermiso": 2,
            "nombre": "Remediación",
            "idUsuario": 11478,
            "email": "labm"
        },
        {
            "idPermiso": 1,
            "nombre": "Catálogos",
            "idUsuario": 12338,
            "email": "BGARCIA"
        },
        {
            "idPermiso": 2,
            "nombre": "Remediación",
            "idUsuario": 12338,
            "email": "BGARCIA"
        }
    ]
```

Están bien pero, quisiera reordenarlos de la siguiente manera para evitar duplicar datos innecesarios como el ID o el email del usuario.

```
"datos": [
         "user": {
            "idUsuario": 12338,
            "email": "BGARCIA" 
            "permisos": [
            {                
               "idPermiso": 1,
               "nombre": "Catálogos"
            },
            {                
               "idPermiso": 2,
               "nombre": "Catálogos 2"
            }
        },
        "user": {
            "idUsuario": 12338,
            "email": "LABM" 
            "permisos": [
            {                
               "idPermiso": 1,
               "nombre": "Catálogos"
            }
        }
    ]
```

He estado intentando con diccionarios pero aún no consigo dar el formato que quiero, ¿podrían darme una idea?

Anexo también el WebMethod en el cual devuelvo el JSON, verán que estoy intentando realizar esto con diccionarios, actualmente estoy jugando con ellos.

***Nota
Solo quiero hacer este formato en la parte del if(idUsuario == -1), la parte del else está bien así como está.***

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static RespuestaJS ObtenerPermisosXUsuario(int idUsuario)
{
    RespuestaJS respuestaJS = new RespuestaJS();
    try
    {
        DataAccessPermiso dataAccess = new DataAccessPermiso();
        RespuestaBD respuestaBD = new RespuestaBD();
        List<object> usuarioPermisosLista = new List<object>();

        respuestaBD = dataAccess.ObtenerPermisosXUsuario(idUsuario);
        List<object> permisos = new List<object>();
        int temp = 0;
        if (respuestaBD.transaccion == 1)
        {
            if (idUsuario == -1)
            {
                var arg = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();
                var data = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                foreach (DataRow fila in respuestaBD.datos.Rows)
                {
                    int idUser = (int)fila["IdUsuario"];
                    if (idUser == temp)
                    {
                        object permisoItem = new
                        {
                            idPermiso = fila["nidPermiso"],
                            nombre = fila["sNombre"]
                        };
                        permisos.Add(permisoItem);
                        arg.Add("user", permisos);
                        data.Add("data", arg);
                    }
                    temp = idUser;
                };

                respuestaJS.transaccion = RespuestaJS.EXITO;
                respuestaJS.datos = arg;
                respuestaJS.mensaje = "ok";
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < respuestaBD.datos.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow fila = respuestaBD.datos.Rows[i];

                    object permisoItem = new
                    {
                        idPermiso = fila["nidPermiso"],
                        nombre = fila["sNombre"],
                        idUsuario = fila["IdUsuario"],
                        email = fila["Email"]
                    };
                    usuarioPermisosLista.Add(permisoItem);
                }

                respuestaJS.transaccion = RespuestaJS.EXITO;
                respuestaJS.datos = usuarioPermisosLista;
                respuestaJS.mensaje = "ok";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            respuestaJS.transaccion = RespuestaJS.ERROR;
            respuestaJS.mensaje = "Error al consultar o ningún resultado coincide";
            respuestaJS.datos = null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        respuestaJS.transaccion = RespuestaJS.ERROR;
        respuestaJS.datos = null;
        respuestaJS.mensaje = ex.Message;
    }

    return respuestaJS;
}
```

Comment: podrías indicarnos el cuerpo del metodo que retorna el primer json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que algo así te podría servir. Básicamente es agrupar con LinQ por IdUsuario.

He utilizado Newtonsoft para facilitar la notación en `Json`:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = "[{'idPermiso':1,'nombre':'Catálogos','idUsuario':11478,'email':'labm'},{'idPermiso':2,'nombre':'Remediación','idUsuario':11478,'email':'labm'},{'idPermiso':1,'nombre':'Catálogos','idUsuario':12338,'email':'BGARCIA'},{'idPermiso':2,'nombre':'Remediación','idUsuario':12338,'email':'BGARCIA'}]";
        var permisos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Permiso>>(json);       
        var usuarios = permisos.GroupBy(item => item.IdUsuario, 
              (key, group) =>  new Usuario { IdUsuario = key, Email = group.FirstOrDefault().Email  ,  Permisos = group.ToList()})
     .ToList() ;
        foreach(var u in usuarios){
            u.Dump();
        }

    }
}

public class Usuario{
    public long IdUsuario{get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Permiso> Permisos {get;set;}
}


public class Permiso{
    public long IdPermiso {get;set;}
    public string Nombre {get;set;}
    public long IdUsuario {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
}
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo aquí: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mDv0eF

*la función Dump() es de dotnetfiddle y la utilizo para "dumplear" la variable en la salida del programa.

Comment: Es necesario utilizar la clase IEnumerable ? o puedo hacerlo con cualquier otro tipo de dato?

Comment: El IEnumerable es el genérico más utilizado para "listas", pero lo puedes reemplazar con cualquiera de sus implementaciones, List<T> por ejemplo.